# Setting ActiveRecord::Errors object to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord, tdd

I am trying to add unit tests to a part of my project that deals with displaying errors.

In order to test for correct handling in a case where there is no ActiveRecord::Errors object to iterate through, I am trying to delete the errors object (not the individual errors) from an otherwise-working test fixture (`@customer`).

I had hoped `@customer.errors = nil` would do the job, but it is raising an error.

Test case:

```
  test "Errors_WhenErrorsObjectNotFound_RaisesNoErrors" do
    log_in_as(@customer)
    @customer.errors = nil
    get :edit, id: @customer
    assert_nothing_raised
  end
```

Unit being tested (should not be relevant but just in case):

```
<% if errors.count == 0 || errors.nil? %>
  <div class="success">
　　  <ul>
      <li>Update successful</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="error">
　　  <ul>
      <% errors.full_messages.each do |err| %>
        <li><%= err %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Error generated:

```
  3) Error:
CustomersControllerTest#test_Errors_WhenErrorsObjectNotFound_RaisesNoErrors:
NoMethodError: undefined method `errors=' for #<Customer:0x9b0f958>
    test/controllers/customers_controller_test.rb:184:in `block in <class:CustomersControllerTest>'
```

Any suggestions on how to delete the errors object?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [ActiveModel::Errors#clear.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-clear)

```
test "Errors_WhenErrorsObjectNotFound_RaisesNoErrors" do
  log_in_as(@customer)
  @customer.errors.clear
  get :edit, id: @customer
  assert_nothing_raised
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this appears to be the opposite of what I want - this removes error messages from the errors object, rather than removing the errors object itself. My aim is to make the "errors" object itself nil, to ensure correct handling of such a case.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a case where `errors` is nil? In my experience, it's always either blank (`{}`) or non-blank (`{'foo' => ['bar']}`) when dealing with an ActiveRecord::Base class.

Comment: Probably not. However, I am trying to apply best practice for unit testing by testing the unit stand-alone making no assumptions about input. In fact we did have problems in the past because this unit sometimes gets used with non-ActiveRecord objects (albeit ones that were subsequently made to implement ActiveRecord::Errors), so having it error-proof in case additional such situations arise in future makes some sense, I think.

Comment: This is looking like a redundant point anyway, because the method I have used for adding errors does not appear to make it through to the view anyway - even in the case where I add two new errors, the view completely ignores them!